# How do I grab all rows from a single column from multiple tables, based on user input?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a Process selection app and I'm not even sure if my approach is correct (I'm new, sorry!).  I have a form with 5 input parameters using radio buttons (choose 1-10).

[image: Form]

I have 5 tables setup for each of those parameters that stores the name of the process and fields set as 1 - 10 to correspond to the user input...One of them looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLC7n.jpg)

I am looking to store each parameters user input (1-10) as a session variable to output to an array for further calculation.

I have the following code that sets the session variables from the form and returns only those records that match user input from only one parameter:

```
    <?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "selectionapp";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['temperature'] = $_POST['temperature'];
 $_SESSION['partSize'] = $_POST['partSize'];
 $_SESSION['volume'] = $_POST['volume'];
 $_SESSION['stiffness'] = $_POST['stiffness'];
 $_SESSION['weight'] = $_POST['weight'];

 } 

echo $_SESSION['temperature'];
echo $_SESSION['partSize'];
echo $_SESSION['volume'];
echo $_SESSION['stiffness'];
echo $_SESSION['weight'];



$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM processes WHERE temperature LIKE '%{$_SESSION['temperature']}%'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo "<table border='1'>";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['score'] .'</td>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['temperature'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['partSize'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['volume'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['stiffness'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['tool'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['paint'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';

}
echo '</table>';

?> 


<?php 
// close connection 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Except, what I think I really need is to grab the one column that matches the user input (1-10) from each of the 5 tables, to create anew array so that I can use those values in a calculation that will score/rank that process type.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you exactly need. Am I correct if I think you need this?: 1. The user makes a selection. 2. The data has to be stored into the database. 3. The same data needs to be given into a session. 4. You want to use these session variables to make calculations?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. Not necessarily...I suppose I can store the reference data in an array? 3. The data from the session must be compared to the reference data (database or array?)  4. No, the session data is only to identify the column from which the calculations will use.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure if this is what you need:

```
// You can start to create an array:
$array = [];

// Next is to set the $array with data
$array = [
    'temperature' => (int) $_POST['temperature'],
    'partSize'    => (int) $_POST['partSize'],
];

// In case you want to echo a piece of the array simply do this:
echo $array['temperature'];

// If you want to 'add' a number to the current one you can do this:
$array['partSize'] = ($array['partSize'] + (int) $_POST['partSize']);

// Do a check if $_POST data actually exist and/or is valid:
$array = [
    'temperature' => (isset($_POST['temperature'])) ? (int) $_POST['temperature'] : 0,
    'partSize'    => (isset($_POST['partSize'])) ? (int) $_POST['partSize'] : 0,
];
```

To be honest, I would personally **not** store this within a session everytime you get new data. Simply do one query and get all data into one array, and calculate these.

For example:

```
// Set $temperature
$temperature = [];

// Query to get all temperature's and put into an array:
$temperature = [1, 6, 3, 8, 2, 9, 10, 3, 7, 9];

// Count how many items you've got
$count_temperature = count($temperature); // = 10

// Now calculate and get an average
$sum_temperature = 0;

foreach ($temperature as $temp)
{
    $sum_temperature = ($sum_temperature + $temp);
}

echo $sum_temperature; // 58

$avg_temperature = ($sum_temperature / $count_temperature);

echo $avg_temperature; // 5.8
```

I hope you get the idea behind it and this answers your question. You are not forced to use a database connection, it could be stored into a `$_SESSION`. But please let me reminder you once the session is destroyed, the input will be lost. If this **DOES NOT** answer your question, please let me know and I will help you find for a solution!

Comment: I can use this, thank you!  Except I'm missing one piece...I need only the array value from each parameter (temp, size, etc.) based on the input...maybe I can edit the question...

Comment: So, I have 5 tables (temperature, partsize, volume, stiffness, weight).  These tables contain the columns (ID, type...and then columns named one, two, three...thru 10).  the type is the process type, say "injection molding"...the columns one to ten have values based on how good a fit they are on the user input 1-10 scale.  a value of, say, "1" is a good fit.  A value of "0" is not.  If the user selects TWO on the form, I need to grab all the values of that TWO column (including type).  Same for partSize...if they select THREE, grab all values from that column.

Comment: Check this note: // Next is to set the $array with data. You can add the other parts to it from the post data. Personally I do not want to trust the user, you csn easily manipulate the data. So to make sure the data is approved, use the 5th note which checks ‘isset’. I think that will do it, isnt it?

Comment: Ok, for that simply put it in an array like the 5th note says. Then you can edit the array with the 4th note calculation (calculate and overwrite). Currently i am on my mobile, so i can not write an example. If you wish to receive an example just say it, but i cant do it earlier than tomorrow (in about 16 hours)

Comment: Temperature Table
[ID, type, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
[1, process1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, process2, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0]
[3, process3, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0]
If user selects TWO for temperature, I need back only:
process1, 0.5
process2, 0

Comment: Awesome it worked! Feel free to mark a question as 'the answer', so your question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!  It is NOT pretty nor concise nor elegant...but it works.  Thank you @RonnieOosting!  While I did not go the array route, you helped point me in the right direction.

```
    <?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "selectionapp";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['temperature'] = $_POST['temperature'];
 $_SESSION['partSize'] = $_POST['partSize'];
 $_SESSION['volume'] = $_POST['volume'];
 $_SESSION['stiffness'] = $_POST['stiffness'];
 $_SESSION['weight'] = $_POST['weight'];
 } 

echo $_SESSION['temperature'];
echo $_SESSION['partSize'];
echo $_SESSION['volume'];
echo $_SESSION['stiffness'];
echo $_SESSION['weight'];


if ($result_temp = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE '%{$_POST['temperature']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['temperature']}%'"));


echo "<table border='1'>";

        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . 'Process Type' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . 'Temperature Score' . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_temp)) {


        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$_SESSION['temperature']] * 10 . "</td>";

        echo '<tr/>';

}
echo '</table>';



$result_size = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM partSize WHERE '%{$_POST['partSize']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['partSize']}%'");
//$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . 'Process Type' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . 'Part Size Score' . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_size)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$_SESSION['partSize']] . "</td>";

        echo '<tr/>';

}
echo '</table>';

$result_vol = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM volume WHERE '%{$_POST['volume']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['volume']}%'");
//$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . 'Process Type' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . 'Volume Score' . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_vol)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$_SESSION['volume']] . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';

}
echo '</table>';

$result_stiff = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stiffness WHERE '%{$_POST['stiffness']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['stiffness']}%'");
//$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . 'Process Type' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . 'Stiffness Score' . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_stiff)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$_SESSION['stiffness']] . "</td>";

        echo '<tr/>';

}
echo '</table>';

$result_wght = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM weight WHERE '%{$_POST['weight']}%' LIKE '%{$_SESSION['weight']}%'");
//$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . 'Process Type' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . 'Weight Score' . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_wght)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$_SESSION['weight']] . "</td>";

        echo '<tr/>';

}
echo '</table>';

echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . 'LFI Results' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . 'Score' . "</td>";
        echo '<tr/>';


        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$_SESSION['weight']] . "</td>";

        echo '<tr/>';


echo '</table>';



?> 


<?php 
// close connection 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This outputs:

Process Type    Temperature Score
LFI              5
DCPD             5
SMC              10

Process Type    Part Size Score
LFI             0.0
DCPD            0.0
SMC             1.0

Process Type    Volume Score
LFI             0.5
DCPD            0.5
SMC             1.0

Process Type    Stiffness Score
LFI             1.0
DCPD            1.0
SMC             1.0

Process Type    Weight Score
LFI             1.0
DCPD            1.0
SMC             1.0